# Can I use a visa in my old passport that was previously reported as stolen?

Tags: visas, passports, lost-documents

This is my issue: I was robbed and my passport was stolen with my ATM cards. I went to the nearest police station to make a police report and an affidavit as I was advised to get a new passport before proceeding to the consular office. Which I did within a few days. A day after I got the new passport, I got a call from the police that my passport has been recovered along with the other stolen items.

So I went to the immigration office and told them that my passport had been recovered and asked if I need to go to the embassy again. I was told that I don’t need to go the embassy as all they will need to do is to cancel my old passport without tampering with my US valid visa on it, since I got a new passport and was told that I will need to hold both my new passport and old passport while traveling.

So I want to ask if this is right and won’t give me a problem at the US port of entry? Thanks.

Comment: Who told you that you don't need to go to the embassy? I'd be extremely concerned about trying to use a visa in a passport that you've previously reported stolen, as that information is entered into an international database, and you could be accused of being the thief. I wouldn't do this without an authoritative written answer from US CBP saying it is ok.

Comment: @ZachLipton It's actually rather unlikely that the police would report the stolen passport to the home country.  That's the embassy's responsibility, and apparently the OP did *not* contact them.

Comment: @zach Lipton ..Note :I HAVENT REPORTED IT STOLEN TO THE EMBASSEY  .... I only reported my passport stolen to the immigration so a to get an emergency quick one .. during the short time frame , I was called by the police that my passport has been recovered but the new passport I applied for was out already..... I hope you get my point now

Comment: @jpatokal the police should enter the stolen passport in the international database of stolen passports, should they not?

Comment: @jpatokal... police and embassy are two different bodies .. and also , my passport is my home base(Nigeria) passport that carries a US valid visa and also since it was recovered , its thier duty to return it back to me... Its the job of the immigration office to deactivate it and not the police

Comment: If you've reported the theft to the authorities in your country, they should have added it to Interpol's database. [The US checks that database](https://www.justice.gov/interpol-washington/pr/interpol-stolenlost-travel-document-database) to identify people who may be trying to use lost or stolen documents. I would enquire with the consulate, via the same channels you would [report a lost/stolen visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/lost-stolen-visas.html) to see what they say, and carry a copy of that response if they say it is ok to travel.

Comment: @zach Lipton .. I don't understand you ... it's my passport I lost it and found it but before it was found , I applied for another one which is has already been registered stolen with the immigration.. so if the US contacts the immigration, they will find the record there and also find the record that I have been reissued..( BUT MY VISA ON IT IS STILL VALID)...So what they did was to cancel my old passport and give me the new one and since my visa is still valid on the cancelled one , I will need to be using the both since the passport still carries  the same profile

Comment: This is a question I want to be sure of ... @zach Lipton ..... Is a Us visa on a stolen passport still valid ?? Considering the fact that It HASNT  been reported to the Us embassy stolen

Comment: My point is that when you told your government that you passport was stolen, they should have reported it to an international database of stolen passports. The US checks that database and can tell the passport was reported stolen. That could lead to a major problem at immigration if you have one registered stolen passport and one new one. I don't know for sure whether or not it will be a problem, but I, personally, wouldn't want to risk showing up at the border holding a Nigerian passport that has been reported stolen. This is why I'm suggesting you contact the consulate.

Comment: @zach Lipton .. oh now I get your point .. I will still contact the Us consulate like you said but I know that my case can never be the first which has been encountered before .. I forgot to inform you that the immigration has cancelled the old passport by indicating a CANCEL stamp on which shows that it was lost but found and cannot be used anymore since its has been reissued but I can still make use of it due to my valid US visa on it since it has been reissued ...Do you get the point now ? But not withstanding .. I will still contact the US consulate